# Magento 2 - Add NEGATIVE discount in catalogue price rules

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I'm trying to use the catalog price rule to add a NEGATIVE percentage to the recorded catalog price - but Magento won't allow that.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the catalogue price is £100, then by adding -20% (minus 20%) it should display £120 in the frontend.

Basically I'd like to use this as a percentage pricing workaround solution to allow me to add price markup by products, categories, etc.

Comment: Why not you using custom code and update the product pricing. Create a section in admin and write you own code.

Comment: Sukumark Gorai  because this way I can set different rules by products, category, etc... and tweak things around when needed if you know what I mean...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way to do the same thing:

1. increasing the rate from `stores-> currency rates`
2. Add discount percentage as much as increased %

example:

```
£100  -> 120
      -> 20  ( increased value )
calculate as Percentage to discount : 100*20/120 = 16.6666
```

if applied 120 - 120*16.66/100 ~ 100

if the rule is not applied the price will be 120